# Traditional login in a laravel app gives InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90: Driver [login] not supported

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1, laravel-socialite

I have a site that allows users to register via social auth using [Laravel socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite) or traditionally using a **registration form**. I have also created a profile controller that is linked to the user, and it should only be accessed on logging in hence I have used `middleware('auth')` on the profile controller.

When I log in traditionally and try to access a profile, I get the following error `InvalidArgumentException in Manager.php line 90:
Driver [login] not supported.`

The sample message of the exception is:

`in Manager.php line 90
at Manager->createDriver('login') in Manager.php line 63
at Manager->driver('login') in Facade.php line 214
at Facade::__callStatic('driver', array('login')) in DinerAuthController.php line 77
at Socialite::driver('login') in DinerAuthController.php line 77
at DinerAuthController->redirectToProvider('login')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(DinerAuthController), 'redirectToProvider'), array('provider' => 'login')) in Controller.php line 256
at Controller->callAction('redirectToProvider', array('provider' => 'login')) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 164
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(DinerAuthController), object(Route), 'redirectToProvider') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 112`.

When I remove the middleware authentication then there's no error.

Has someone encountered a similar error? **Anyone with a viable solution please help me out**.

The following is the sample code of the files involved.

**DinerAuthController.php**

```
public function postDinerSignin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);
    if (! Auth::diner()->attempt(
        $request->only(['email', 'password']),
        $request->has('remember')
    )) {
        return redirect()->route('dinerhome')->with('info', 'Could not sign you 
            in with those credentials.');
    }
    $request->session()->put('user_id', Auth::diner()->get()->id);

    return redirect()->route('dinerhome')->with('info', 'You are now  signed in');
}

public function redirectToProvider($provider)
{
    return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($provider)
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return Redirect::to('auth/{provider}');
    }

    $authUser = $this->findOrCreateUser($user);

    Auth::diner()->login($authUser, true);

    return redirect()->route('dinerhome');
}
```

DinerAuthController.php line 77 is `return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();`

**config/services.php:**

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_URL'),
],

'twitter' => [
    'client_id' => env('TWITTER_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('TWITTER_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('TWITTER_URL'),
],

'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => env('FACEBOOK_URL'),
]
```

**DinerProfileController.php :**

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using the **Gate Facade** for authorization.
After defining the ability, I checked it via the Gate Facade and redirected the user if the check fails.

**DinerProfileController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    if (Gate::denies('diner')) {
        return redirect()->route('login')->send();
    }
}
```